# Security model using asp.net Identity 2

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I need ideas about a security model preferably using asp.net identity 2

A web site that I develop can have many registered companies.  Each company can have a one or many users.
When users log-in they are presented with the ‘things’ that ‘belong’ to their company (same products, same suppliers, same clients, same documents, etc).
For instance, if you are a user of company A and I am a user of company B when you log-in you see those ‘things’ that belong to company A, and when I log-in I see those ‘things’ that belong to company B.

I do want to enable users to use their social network log-in credentials if so they wish.

My questions are related to the security part -

- How would you register the companies and then specify who your users are?
- How would you authenticate each user and associate that user
  to a specific company?
- How would you decide who should be the first admin of that company?

Many Thanks,
Richard